# Shared Postgres Relation Best Practices

Tags: postgresql

What is the best practice to encode this relationship in a postgres database schema?

Given the following entities: `Document, Profile, Message`

And the following relationships:

```
One Profile to many Documents

One Message to many Documents
```

Essentially documents are a shared resource used by other entities. Should I use different `Join Tables` for each related entity? Is there some other way to set this up? It is possible in the future that other entities will reference `Documents`

Comment: Hi Justin, SO is not intended to ask for advice on best practices. Instead, you should describe a specific problem you are faced with, what you have done to resolve it, what you are expecting and what you are getting instead.

Comment: I am trying to create the relationship schema above. The problem being that in PSQL One-To-Many relationships are accompanied by Many-To-One relationships. My Document resource should be agnostic to Profiles, Messages, etc. So I would like to avoid a Many-To-One relationship in the Document schema.

Comment: This forum is so overly pedantic. The title is essentially 'How to create a shared postgres relation'. -2 as of commenting. I feel like this is incredibly valid question to ask of a database sub-forum.

Comment: Your issue is clearly explained in any number of database modelling primers on the internet. Shall I google this for you? If you are not pleased with how SO works, you are looking in the wrong place for answers.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this post and wants an actual answer: The foreign key for the relation HAS to be on the many-to-one side of the relationship or there has to be a join table mapping the relation. You cannot store multiple foreign keys in a single column on the one-to-many side of the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

A one-to-many relationship is modeled with a foreign key, in this case in the `documents` table. If you need two such relationships, define two foreign keys.